# Count the numbers stored in a column and display them

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello I have a database that contains the following setup

```
id  |  message
1      5
2      5
3      6
```

in the message columns I have certain integers that can be duplicate. The thing I want to get now is to have all the message values AND how many time they appear in the column.

So the output should be

```
5(2)
6(1)
```

Can someone help me out how the query should be?

Comment: Given that you don't know something this basic, I've heard good things about the book, Teach Yourself SQL in 10 Minutes.

Comment: Or an on-line tutorial:  [Clicky!](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/)

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(*) as frequency, message from table_name group by message;
```

For your sample data, this should return:

```
frequency  message
    2         5
    1         6
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (id INT, message INT)
INSERT INTO @T
VALUES
(1,5),
(2,5),
(3,6)

SELECT Message , COUNT(*) NumOfMsgs
FROM @T
GROUP BY Message
```

**Result Set**

```
Message NumOfMsgs
 5        2
 6        1
```